# iPhone + In App purchase + change alert message

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, alerts

I have implemented In App Purchase in one of the existing application, it's working fine. But the problem is that whenever I tap on any of the locked feature (where I have implemented In App code), it show me the alert message with title like

"Confirm your In App Purchase"

and message saying

"Do you want to buy one xxx Features for $xxx ?" and

"Cancel" / "Buy" UIButtons.

I am not setting any of these messages in code, so I don't know where is this text coming from and how to change this message with something like

"This Feature is locked, do you want to buy this feature and unlock it ?"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The messages are coming from the App Store, so that you can not change the text. You must go the other direction. When the user taps a button or a table vie cell related to a locked feature, then you show youe message asking the user to buy it. If he/she confirms, then the App Store message appears.